# Change behaviour of “Turn Off Computer” button

Tags: windows-xp

I asked this question on Stack Overflow originally but was redirected here.

I'm hoping to alter the behaviour of "Turn Off Computer" (in Start) so it calls a script rather than shutting down (the script will then shut down the computer at EOF). I've tried running .bat files in Group Policy but those scripts run after network connections have been closed, and I need to backup certain files on several computers in a network to a NAS.

OS is Windows XP, and XP's Scheduled Tasks don't give the option to run at Shutdown.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have given a +1 (which removes your negative vote) Let's delete our comments as they're not helpful to your post